# How Can I make 2 transition form 1 state? in Unity2D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made 1 transition from a state in the animator controller and I tried to make 
one another transition from the same state, but there is no "make transition" menu.
How can I make 2 transition from 1 state?
Unity Version is 2020.3.32f1.
I put the picture  when I couldn't make another transition.
I think it seems the menu is something strange..
There is no "Make transition" menu.

[image: no make transition menu]

Answer (score 0):

Right click in the state where you want to start transitioning

Comment: yeah,I did right click, but there was no "Make transition" menu. Attached is a picture of me right clicking on it.

Answer (score 0):

I updated Unity Editor version to 2020.3.33f1, and it fixed.
I think it's seems  bug in 2020.3.32.f1.